# Why is this accept invite php script not working (discord api and curl)

Tags: php, curl, discord

At the end it says: Json deserialize error: key must be a string at line 1 column 2

I've tried a bunch of different things but they all don't work. I can't recall all of them and I'm pretty bad at this kind of stuff, so I wanted help

```php
$url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/' . $_GET["invite"] . '?with_counts=true';

$ch = curl_init();
$payload = json_encode($payload);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: ' . $_GET["token"]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Referer: https://discordapp.com/channels/@me'
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
$data = json_decode($response);

echo "<br/><br/>";

$url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/science';
$data = json_decode($response);
$json = '{channel_id: "' . $data->channel->id . '", channel_type: "0", client_performance_cpu: 48.87893460435096, client_performance_memory: 833620, client_send_timestamp: ' . time() . ', client_track_timestamp: ' . time() . ', client_uuid: "IQAECB1soghXJlZ+EXiHFG4BAAATAwAA", code: "' . $_GET["invite"] . '", destination_user_id: null, guild_id: "' . $data->guild->id  . '", invite_type: "Server Invite", inviter_id: "' . $data->inviter->id  . '", location: "Join Guild Modal", resolved:, true size_online: ' . $data->approximate_presence_count . ', size_total: ' . $data->approximate_member_count . ', type: "resolve_invite", token: "' . $_GET["token"] . '"';
$ch = curl_init();
$payload = json_decode($json);
$json = $json . "}";

echo $json;

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: ' . $_GET["token"]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $json
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<br/><br/>" . $response;
?>
```

The response is

```
Json deserialize error: key must be a string at line 1 column 2
```